# Error while connecting to Teradata database with PHP odbc at Red Hat Linux 6

Tags: php, linux, odbc, teradata, unixodbc

I have a Red Hat Linux 6 with Apache and PHP installed and running. I have installed the MS SQL Server and Teradata driver, and I am able to connect and execute queries to these databases via iSQL on the server terminal.

When I try to use the ODBC connection through a PHP script, I am able to connect and execute queries on a MS SQL Server, but if I try to connect to a Teradata database, I get this error message:

> Warning: odbc_connect(): SQL error: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't
>   open lib '/opt/teradata/client/14.10/odbc_64/lib/tdata.so' : file not
>   found, SQL state 01000

This file, tdata.so, **exists** in the referenced location, and has all possible permissions.

The php code is:

```
$con_string = "DRIVER={Teradata};DBCName=SERVER; DATABASE=MYDB;";
$con = odbc_pconnect( $con_string , "USER", "PASSWORD" );
```

The odbc.ini file (located in /etc/odbc.ini) has this content:

```
[Teradata]
Driver=/opt/teradata/client/14.10/odbc_64/lib/tdata.so
Description=Teradata database
DBCName=SERVER
LastUser=
Username=
Password=
Database=
DefaultDatabase=

[MSSQL]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server A
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.1.so.0.1
UsageCount=1
```

When I execute the command:

```
ldd /opt/teradata/client/14.10/odbc_64/lib/tdata.so
```

I get this response:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffff03ff000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fb736c1e000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fb736a07000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fb7367ea000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fb7365e6000)
librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007fb7363dd000)
libnsl.so.1 => /lib64/libnsl.so.1 (0x00007fb7361c4000)
libodbcinst.so => /opt/teradata/client/14.10/odbc_64/lib/libodbcinst.so (0x00007fb735fa0000)
libddicu26.so => /opt/teradata/client/14.10/odbc_64/lib/libddicu26.so (0x00007fb7350a8000)
libtdparse.so => /opt/teradata/client/14.10/odbc_64/lib/libtdparse.so (0x00007fb734f22000)
libicudatatd.so.46 => /usr/lib64/libicudatatd.so.46 (0x00007fb7346d8000)
libicuuctd.so.46 => /usr/lib64/libicuuctd.so.46 (0x00007fb73444a000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007fb7341c6000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fb733e32000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003727400000)
```

The path seems correctly configured too, when I execute the command:

```
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

I get this response:

```
/opt/teradata/client/14.10/odbc_64/lib:/opt/teradata/client/14.10/lib:/opt/teradata/client/14.10/tbuild/lib:/opt/teradata/client/14.00/odbc_64/lib::/usr/lib
```

I cannot understand what is wrong, I have tried various possible solutions, but nothing is working for me. Can Anybody help?

Comment: Are you running the php on the same node where odbc is configured?

Comment: Yes, PHP and ODBC were installed at the same time in the same server.